# NativeBase multiple icons in InputGroup

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I'm trying to make an `InputGroup` that has two icons OR one icon and one button.

One icon should be used to check if the input field is empty or not (got that working). The other icon OR button should be used to "inject" some text into the `Input` field.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Content, List, InputGroup, Input, Icon, Button } from 'native-base'
export default class AddEquipment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      parameters:  {
        one: {value:"", hint: "One"},
        two: {value:"", hint: "Two"},
        three: {value:"Valid", hint: "Three"}
      }
    }

    this.updateParameter = this.updateParameter.bind(this)
    this.validationStyle = this.validationStyle.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }

  updateParameter(key, value) {
    newState = {...this.state}
    newState.parameters[key].value = value
    this.setState = newState;
  }

  validationStyle(text) {
    color = text === "" ? "#b03939" : "#649370"
    return (
      { marginRight:25, color
      }
    )
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Content>
        { Object
          .keys(this.state.parameters)
          .map( key =>
            <InputGroup
              key={`${key}_InputGroup`}
              iconRight
              borderType='regular'
              style={{margin:5}}
              >

              <Input
                placeholder={this.state.parameters[key].hint}
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                  console.log(this.state.parameters)
                  this.updateParameter(key, text)} }
                value={key.value}
              />

              <Icon
                key={`${key}_validIcon`}
                name={ this.state.parameters[key].value === "" ? 'ios-alert' : 'ios-checkmark-circle'}
                style={ this.validationStyle(this.state.parameters[key].value) }
              />

              <Icon
                key={`${key}_injectNA`}
                name='ios-beer'
                onPress={() => this.updateParameter(key, "Cheers!") }/>

            </InputGroup>
          )
        }
      </Content>
    )
  }
}
```

Which gives me the following result

[image: output]

## First issue

As you can see I have trouble getting the other icon appear - it doesn't seem to lie behind the first.

A button would be as good, but it always drops below the `Input` and not next to it. Styling is not my strongest style - hence why I use the awesome framework NativeBase

## Second issue

Another problem I have is that the validation does not seem to change icon and color after the `state` is being updated. Seems like the `style` are loaded only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on the **first issue** would you consider validity icon in front? InputGroup can dispay maximum two icons: before and after text input, see code below.

on the **second issue** it's caused that you assign value to the state, while in React you should call this.setState(newState), see [reference](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state)

another issue is accessing to the object key's value by key.value, while key is just a string (key name), while real object accessed by this.state.parameters[key]

Following code fixes all mentioned issues (but validity icon is on the left):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Content, List, InputGroup, Input, Icon, Button } from 'native-base'

const errorStyle = {color: "#b03939"}
const validStyle = {color: "#649370"}

export default class AddEquipment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      parameters:  {
        one: {value:"", hint: "One"},
        two: {value:"", hint: "Two"},
        three: {value:"Valid", hint: "Three"}
      }
    }

    this.updateParameter = this.updateParameter.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }

  updateParameter(key, value) {
    let newState = {...this.state}
    newState.parameters[key].value = value
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  static validationStyle(text) {
    return text === "" ? errorStyle : validStyle;
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Content>
        { Object
          .keys(this.state.parameters)
          .map( key =>
            <InputGroup
              key={`${key}_InputGroup`}
              borderType='regular'
              style={{margin:5}}
              >

              <Icon
                  key={`${key}_validIcon`}
                  name={ this.state.parameters[key].value === "" ? 'ios-alert' : 'ios-checkmark-circle'}
                  style={ AddEquipment.validationStyle(this.state.parameters[key].value) }
                />

              <Input
                placeholder={this.state.parameters[key].hint}
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                  console.log(this.state.parameters)
                  this.updateParameter(key, text)} }
                value={this.state.parameters[key].value}
              />

              <Icon
                key={`${key}_injectNA`}
                name='ios-beer'
                onPress={() => this.updateParameter(key, "Cheers!") }/>

            </InputGroup>

          )
        }
      </Content>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out. I can't test your answer before after christmas. But I do believe that it will work since I came across http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.13/components#searchBar and saw that I should just have put the first `Icon` before the `Input`

Comment: BTW I had to do `this.forceUpdate` to update the validation icon

Comment: You don't need to do it with the above code, since setState() will call for rerender. With forceUpdate you worked around misuse of setState ;-)

Comment: It is important to remove "iconRight" property from IconGroup. Actually placing Icon before or after Input won't make difference, it's just more readable, but the key is when iconRight specified only one Icon displayed, while when iconRight=false first Icon is displayed to the left, second is to the right of the Input field.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It really helped me to move on